# What solid does the truncation of an icosahedron approach?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, 3d, polyhedra, solid-geometry

i was watching some old maths fun related stuff on youtube, and i stumbled across this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwWBpjeyRS0 in which the guy mentions how a football is obtained by truncating an icosahedron in a certain way, so i was wondering: what happens if you iterate the process? I mean, if you truncate the "football" shape he's talking about you get a thing with lots of triangle-ish faces i think, but what if you keep doing that? Does it approach a sphere? Does it become "smooth" at some point?

Comment: I think you get some kind of fractal thing, really.

Comment: Idk, i can't really recognise any clear pattern in it

Comment: Go to [polypolyHédronisme](https://levskaya.github.io/polyhedronisme/) with
a recent browser. Input `I` to the REICPE field to get a [icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron),
`tI` to get a football = [truncated icosahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron) and repeat the process with `ttI`, `tttI`, ...
The process of `truncation` itself doesn't guarantee the resulting polyhedron is convex. Read the notes there for other options and experiment with yourself.

Comment: @achillehui Thank you! That's what i was looking for!